# I am getting a null in database fields

Tags: laravel

The following code is in view :

```
    <input maxlength="2" value="{{ old('discount') }}" 
     class="form-control" type="text" 
     id="product-discount-in-adding-products" 
     name="discount">
```

and this is my code in controller:

```
if($request->has('discount')){
    $product->discount = $request->discount;
}else{
    $product->discount = 0;
}
```

when I send a form by post my discount fields in a database will give a null.

Comment: Can you show us the form?

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? And what are you putting into the form when you submit it to end up with a `null` in your DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Laravel 5.5, the `has` method on the request object tells you only if the field is actually present in the request, not whether or not it has a value. So if you submit an empty value in your form for `discount`, your first check `if($request->has('discount')){` will be true.

Now, Laravel also has middlewares to trim strings and convert empty strings to null so if you're submitting an empty value in your `discount` field, then you will be setting `$product->discount` to `null`.

The way to check if form contains a value for the specified input, is to use the `filled` method instead:

```
if ($request->filled('discount')) {
    $product->discount = $request->discount;
} else {
    $product->discount = 0;
}
```

This should stop the first check evaluating to `true` and will set `$product->discount` to `0`.

See the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input) under the heading labelled *Determining If An Input Value Is Present*.